# How to properly sort collection of objects so that quantities can be totaled for a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, arraylist, dictionary

Okay so i have a custom class which represents a company saying they have a certain quantity of an item, on a specific date. To simplify my problem, let me say that in this case we are looking only at three important class variables, which are:

```
String partNumber - Contains the part# that a company is saying is in stock.
int quantity - The amount of the item that is in stock.
Calendar dateOfAccess - This variable contains the date the statement was found.
```

What i want to do is take a collection of these objects, and sort them first by part number, then by date of access, so one could loop through part numbers, and inside that loop, have a nested loop that sums up the total number of parts for each day... in order to make a graph of total quantities over time.

This needs to be done in a way that is efficient, and where the code is fairly clear.

What i have already tried:

Assuming the input collection is an arraylist, we could easily set pre-defined part numbers to have the program match, and get an arraylist of all one part number (by the way... there are variations, like "St-56" and "St 56" and "St56", but we could pass in an array of strings and if the object's part number matches any string in this array we can say its part number is matching)

Once we have an array list of an individual part, this becomes the tricky bit. I have tried putting them in an array where the index is the "Time since Jan 1, 2014". In this way if we have arr[index] and our array has dates: Jan 6, Feb 1, Jan 24, Jan 5, Jan 6.... then:

```
arr[5] = (ArrayList containing 1 object with date "Jan 5")
arr[6] = (ArrayList containing 2 objects with date "Jan 6")
arr[24] = (ArrayList containing 1 objects with date "Jan 24")
arr[32] = (ArrayList containing 1 objects with date "Feb 1")
```

This way we could appropriately do some sort of sum:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    int arrayListTotal = arr[i].size();
    ....
}
```

..... and begin to sum up every day of a given part number.

The problem with my approach is that it seems very messy:

1. The collection of items seems very over-complicated (I had an even worse way which involved 'arr[Year][Month][Day][PartNumber] = ArrayList' !)
2. There are gaps in the array since the first day since Jan 1 2014 is actually Jan 5. This has to be accounted for when looking at the final collections, otherwise we would either access a null arraylist, or be graphing "zero items" from Jan 1 to Jan 4, which is false data.

A friend suggested to me to use the Map class. At first glance, this helps somewhat. I could use the part number as a key, and then do another map inside that where the key is the date! However, i read about maps and you may only use one item per key (keys must be unique!). This leads me to believe i need:

```
Map<String partNumKey, Map<Calendar dateKey, ArrayList<Object>>>
```

This also seems very silly in a way, but perhaps it would work. Is there any way that is more simple to read, more elegant, and lends itself to a good way to count up how many part numbers are held by various companies in one day?

So far my feeling is the best idea is this "Map of Maps of ArrayLists of (custom) Objects".

Thanks!

Comment: As i continue to think about this problem, i am beginning to wonder if there really is a less complicated solution. Maybe this problem is cumbersome in its very nature, because i am dealing with so many variables, and don't have a pleasant way to arrange the objects cleanly.

Comment: So it needs to support the query "Give me the part count of each part for a given company for a given day."  Then you would want to call this query for each Company and with a range of days in order to construct your graph.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Hello @DMunz! Very close, i only need to gather "The part count of each part, for each day", in this case the sum will be taken over however many companies are offering the part, so who offers it doesnt matter in this case. Then we could graph every part numbers "Total Quantity Available" over time.

Comment: If that is the case AND that is the only query you want to support, then the "Map of Map of ArrayList" approach is not a bad one. I would recommend that you normalize your part numbers before adding them to the data structure - that is convert all of your "St 56", "st56", ... permutations into one common format to use as the key.  However, if you see yourself needing other queries, you may want to consider using a Relational Database. If you are not familiar with SQL, you might check out this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) to get an idea of the queries supported by RDBs.

Comment: Yes, i was told by a friend a database may help, but i have no prior knowledge of databases other than that each entry needs a unique key. Taking up the learning needed for this seems as complicated as a non-db solution. I will try to read and understand the tutorial though, since a DB has now been suggested to me twice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. (You should try to 'compress' your question to the essetial parts.) As I understand it you want to draw a graph with dates on the x-axis and amount of items available on the y-axis (for one item?)

If this is what you want your final data-structure could be (all following in pseudocode):

`Map<PartNumber,List<Item>>`

While the PartNumber part is the uninteresting one which you will only use the fetch whichever part you want.

Now take the `List<Item>`, order it by date and simply iterate it:

```
List<Item> items = map.get( "ST56sth" );

Collections.sort( items, new MyComparatorByDate() );

int lastday=0, count=0;
for( Item it : items ){

    if( it.day() > lastday ){
       print( count + " items on day " + day ); //Or whatever
       lastday = it.day();
       count = 0;
    }
    count += it.quantity;
}
```

I leave the real code and some small pitfalls for you to fill out :)

Comment: I did try to condense my question already, unfortunately its sort of a complex issue. I hope at least that it is mostly understandable. Your thinking is right, and i am now contemplating how your algorithm would work with what i have.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it seems complicated, I think you're onto something with the nested maps. I also think one reason the use of a database has been suggested is that SQL queries have a clause `GROUP BY` that essentially does what you want to do. That is, it takes individual records (rows) and sorts them so that (say) all the rows with the same part number are grouped together. These `GROUP BY` clauses can be nested, so within the same-part-number group, the rows could be sorted and grouped together by date.

The in-memory data structure that would represent such a grouping would be similar to how you described it:

```
Map<PartNumber, Map<Calendar, List<Custom>>>
```

I've modified your example a bit to use a `PartNumber` type instead of `String` to make it clear what the key is. Continuing with the assumptions :-), let's say your `Custom` class, as you referred to it, looks something like this:

```
class Custom {
    PartNumber getPartNumber() { ... }
    int getQuantity() { ... }
    Calendar getDate() { ... }
}
```

If you've upgraded to Java 8, it's quite simple to run through your input list and sort/group the data records (instances of the `Custom` class) into groups in a `Map` similar to the one described above. This uses the new `java.util.stream` API. in particular, it uses the `Collectors` class, which has the grouping functions. I've used static imports to make things more readable.

Let's start off grouping the input list by part number.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

List<Custom> input = ... ;

Map<PartNumber, List<Custom>> map1 =
    input.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Custom::getPartNumber));
```

This takes the input list, turns it into a stream, and then sends the stream into the `groupingBy` collector. `groupingBy` in turn takes a *classifier function* which is run on each incoming object to extract an object that will be the key in the output map. The incoming objects become values in the map. Since there's the possibility that multiple input records will have the same part number, the ones that do are stored in a `List` that's the value of the map.

Now it gets a little tricky. :-)

We want to do further processing on the list of records that all have the same part number. In particular we want them grouped by date. The way to do this is (similar to SQL) to use a *nested* grouping operation:

```
Map<PartNumber, Map<Calendar, List<Custom>>> map2 =
    input.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Custom::getPartNumber,
            groupingBy(Custom::getDate)));
```

Each value of the outer map, instead of being a list of records, is now a nested map, grouping those records by date.

But we want to do even more processing. Each value in the nested map is a list of records, each of which has the same part number and date. We don't want a list, we want the sum of the quantities from the records in that list. We add yet another nested operation ("collector"), but instead of a grouping collector, we use a different collector that sums integer values. It takes a function that extracts an integer from each record, and then sums those integers, and that sum becomes the value in the nested map instead of the list. The code that does this is:

```
Map<PartNumber, Map<Calendar, Integer>> map3 =
    input.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Custom::getPartNumber,
            groupingBy(Custom::getDate,
                summingInt(Custom::getQuantity))));
```

That's how you can get the total quantity of parts available on each day, for each part number. That might not be exactly what you want, but you can see the flavor of how these grouping operations work and can change things around to solve different problems.

You had also mentioned that there are variations in the part numbers such as "St-56", "St 56", and "St56". Unfortunately the grouping operation works on equality only, so these would be grouped separately. The way I'd suggest you deal with this is first decide which form is to be the "canonical" part number (say, "St-56") and then to create a table (another `Map`) of substitutions. This would look something like:

```
Map<PartNumber, PartNumber> subst = new HashMap<>();
subst.put(PartNumber.of("St 56"), PartNumber.of("St-56"));
subst.put(PartNumber.of("St56"), PartNumber.of("St-56"));
```

Then, use this map to substitute any of the synonym part numbers with the canonical ones in the data records before doing the grouping processing. You probably don't want to modify the input records, so you'd transform any input records with synonym part numbers into new records with the replacement part number. A little helper function that does this would be:

```
Custom substPartNumber(Custom c) {
    if (subst.contains(c.getPartNumber()) {
        return new Custom(subst.get(c.getPartNumber()), c.getQuantity(), c.getDate());
    else
        return c;
}
```

Now you can insert a call to this within a `map` operation in the stream to perform the substitutions:

```
Map<PartNumber, Map<Calendar, Integer>> map3 =
    input.stream()
        .map(c -> substPartNumber(c))
        .collect(groupingBy(Custom::getPartNumber,
            groupingBy(Custom::getDate,
                summingInt(Custom::getQuantity))));
```